# Regex for extracting digits in a string not in a word and not separated by a symbol?

Tags: regex, search

I want to extract an ID from a search query but I don't know the length of the ID.

From this input I want to get the numbers that are not in the words and the numbers that are not separated by symbols.

```
12 11231390 good123e41 12he12o1 1391389 dajue1290a 12331 12-10 1.2 test12.0why 12+12 12*6 2d1139013 09`29 83919 1
```

Here I want to return

```
12 11231390 1391389 12331 83919 1
```

So far I've tried `/\b[^\D]\d*[^\D]\b/gm` but I get the numbers in between the symbols and I don't get the 1 at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could repeatedly match digits between whitespace boundaries. Using a word boundary `\b` would give you partial matches.

Note that `[^\D]` is the same as `\d` and would expect at least a single character.

Your pattern can be written as `\b\d\d*\d\b` and you can see that you don't get the 1 at the end as your pattern matches at least 2 digits.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:\s+\d+)*(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Negateive lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+(?:\s+\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ digits.
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitspace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WowGRV/1)

If lookarounds are not supported, you could use a match with a capture group

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)(?:$|\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLENGk/1)